# Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, opensuse

I am already using Linux, and really did not want to switch to windows, but as fate would have it, i need Windows for my office work.

I have been working on OpenSuSE for almost 2 years and it has been my primary system.
I now wan to install Windows and be able to use OpenSuSE with that.

I know its a naive question but i know too little about windows, always been a linux user.

Comment: What are you asking? Are you wanting to know how to dual boot, put linux in a VM inside windows, put windows in a VM inside linux, ...?

Comment: I already have Linux, I now want to install Windows over it, without Losing Linux.. no VM

Comment: If you don't want to use a VM, then you're only option is to setup a dual boot system.

Answer (score 1):

If your system is powerful enough I would install either Virtualbox or KVM and make use of a virtual machine (VM) where you could run Windows inside of it on your existing system.

If your system is not powerful enough your only other option is to try setting up a dual boot system that would either be running Linux or Windows, but not at the same time.

There are literally dozens and dozens of tutorials and screencasts showing how to setup Virtualbox, so I would simply look for those. Here's one to get you started:

- [The Beginner's Guide to Creating Virtual Machines with VirtualBox](http://lifehacker.com/5204434/the-beginners-guide-to-creating-virtual-machines-with-virtualbox)

#### Installing Windows alongside SuSE

This order is generally the harder of the two. It's generally easier to install Windows first, and then install SuSE (or other distro) afterwards.

Installing Windows along side an installation of SuSE will likely render your Grub bootloader in a unusable state, and so you'll likely need to manually repair it after installing Windows.

The steps to repair it are covered in this OpenSuSE Wiki article, titled: [SDB:Repair MBR after Windows install](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aRepair_MBR_after_Windows_install).